# Are my constraints in this LP problem correct? Any redundant?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to set up an LP problem based on the situation below:

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

Let $b_i$ denote sacks bought at month i (i=1,2,3)

Let $s_i$ denote sacks sold at month i (i=2,3,4)

We want to maximise net return (profit?)

$$z = -28.5b_1 + 31s_1 - 30.5b_2 + 32.5s_2 - 29b_3 + 29.5s_3$$

s.t.

Final inventory must be 20,000

1. $$10,000 - \sum_i s_i + \sum_i b_i = 20,000$$

Nonnegative:

2. $$s_i, b_i \ge 0$$

Cash balance:

3. $$\sum_i c_i b_i \le 2,000,000$$

where $c_1 = 28.5, c_2 = 30.5, c_3 = 29$

Capacity of 50,000 sacks:

4. $$10,000 + b_1 \le 50,000$$
5. $$10,000 + b_1 - s_1 + b_2 \le 50,000$$
6. $$10,000 + b_1 - s_1 + b_2 - s_2 + b_3 \le 50,000$$
7. $$10,000 + b_1 - s_1 + b_2 - s_2 + b_3 - s_3 \le 50,000$$

---

Is that right?

Is constraint #7 redundant due to constraint #1?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third constraint : $$28.5b_1 + 30.5b_2 + 29b_3\le 2,000,000$$ is too restrictive on the cash balance. You don't take into account any revenue in the period.

Try instead:
$$28.5b_1 \le 2,000,000$$
$$28.5b_1 - 31s_1 + 30.5b_2 \le 2,000,000$$
$$28.5b_1 - 31s_1 + 30.5b_2 - 32.5s_2 + 29b_3 \le 2,000,000$$

Yes constraint #7 is redundant due to constraint #1 because constraint #1 is more restrictive.

Comment: I had a feeling something was up with that. Thanks MikeDundee ^-^

Comment: MikeDundee, do we have $$28.5b_1 - 31s_1 + 30.5b_2 - 32.5s_2 + 29b_3 - 29.5s_3 \le 2,000,000$$ which is redundant by $$28.5b_1 - 31s_1 + 30.5b_2 - 32.5s_2 + 29b_3 \le 2,000,000$$ ?